# Advance Methods of Understanding Significance of Customer Behaviors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, feature-selection, exponential-smoothing, z-score

I currently own a couple of websites and lately I've been implementing some feature changes - I've noticed some changes in website traffic and I was wondering what some of the more sophisticated ways are to measure the significance of the change.

I have 2 scenarios:

1. I changed one of my website's background from black to orange, this actually increased the site traffic by 17%.
2. I moved the check out button to a more obvious position on a different site, this specific site unfortunately experienced decreased traffic the day after the implementation by 8%.

I have three questions:

1. I know the somewhat traditional method of measuring significance, basically run a t-test (look up the z-score in a table and see the probability of this happening by chance, and if its <5% then the change is significant, etc). But is there a more advanced (data-science-y) way of measuring the significance of the change? If it's too much to explain, pointing me to a general direction to look is greatly appreciated!
2. Speaking of a more data-science-y approach, I've been thinking about triple-exponential smoothing. I can break the day down by hour and build a model of usage by hour, then I can compare the actual hourly usages to the predicted usages and compare the two. Is this a more sophisticated way to go about this or am I just being dumb?
3. Right now I'm testing out features on different sites in order to minimized interference of the new features I'm implementing. If I implement both these changes to the same site, what are some of the ways I can separate and measure the significance of these two features (kind of similar to partial correlations where I take control of certain variables).
   Thanks for reading! Please let me know your thoughts. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Statistics has been around and has much more concrete definition and math theory than "data science". I am in the data science market myself. But data science doesn't have a concrete definition yet. It is a cocktail of statistics and computer science. I am a bit irked by the notion of a more sophisticated approach than a t-test.

1) A t-test is very sophisticated, and I would suggest you employ it for your websites

2) When you make a model of the previous data and predict what could have been with what is, you are effectively comparing whether or not your real value falls inside the variance of your predicted values. Falling within variance, is... t-test. And I think it is an overkill, as you might be making more assumptions than necessary, leading to more errors.

3) If you want to assess the effects of multiple factors, try ANOVA and f-statistics, learn about them [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/statistics-inferential/anova/v/anova-1-calculating-sst-total-sum-of-squares).